# Perl: Escaping meta characters in split

Tags: perl

I'm trying to use `split()` to extract the value `tiefighter.com` from `leia@tiefighter.com`. I found that if the `@` character in my input string is escaped, I get the expected output:

```
$ perl -e '$string = "leia\@tiefighter.com"; @parts = split(/\@/, $string); print "Domain: $parts[-1]\n";'
Domain: tiefighter.com
```

However, if I do not escape the `@` character, I get this:

```
$ perl -e '$string = "leia@tiefighter.com"; @parts = split(/\@/, $string); print "Domain: $parts[-1]\n";' 
Domain: leia.com
```

Given that I cannot anticipate the input string, what is the correct way to split on the `@`?

Comment: This is why you should turn on warnings, even for one-liners. `perl -wE'say "foo@bar"'` gives 'Name "main::bar" used only once: possible typo at -e line 1.'

Comment: It's only because you're using `@` inside a double-quoted string and `@tiefighter` could be a valid variable name to interpolate. If you're getting your input from somewhere else, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an artifact of specifying the string in the code. The `@` sigil in perl indicates an array, and in a double-quoted string, this gets expanded (or tries to expand, even if `@tiefighter` does not exist).

You can fix either with the backslash, as you already found, or by quoting differently so it's a single-quoted string (thus, not interpolated).

```
perl -e '$string = q{leia@tiefighter.com}; @parts = split(/\@/, $string); print "Domain: $parts[-1]\n";'
```

In real code, you probably aren't statically writing these strings out, and this probably won't be an issue in the first place.

To elaborate on Perl's interpolation: single-quoted values are not interpolated, and double-quoted values are.

```perl
$a = 'abc';
@b = ('abc', 'def');

$foo = 'bar$a';           # 'bar$a'
$foo = "bar$a";           # 'barabc'

$foo = 'bar@b';           # 'bar@b'
$foo = "bar@b";           # 'barabc def'
```

You can get around these problems using proper quoting. Either use single-quoted strings, or alternately you can escape the sigils inside of double-quoted strings.

```perl
$foo = "bar\$a";
$foo = "bar\@b";
```

`q{}` is equivalent to single-quotes as well.

```perl
$foo = q{bar$a bar@b};
```

Of course, like I said, in real code, probably something else is taking care of getting the special symbols into your string, and you won't be writing them out explicitly like this. But in cases where you do need to write things out explicitly, this is how to handle it.

Comment: In real code, you would also have strict and warnings enabled, so you'd get a compile error (unless `@tiefighter` is defined).

Comment: IMO, using the `q//` quoting would be cleaner inside a one-liner, even though it's kind of a moot point.

Comment: Ah okay. I didn't realize there was a distinction in statically declaring a string in double quotes vs a string from a file/stream.

Comment: @DirtyPenguin I expanded the answer to include some examples of how string interpolation works with different quoting and escaping and variable types.

Comment: Hashes don't interpolate. See [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-value-constructors): "Variable substitution inside strings is limited to scalar variables, arrays, and array or hash slices. (In other words, names beginning with `$` or `@`, followed by an optional bracketed expression as a subscript.)"

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Thanks for the reminder. I updated the answer to remove mention of hashes.

Comment: @DanLowe Thank you :)

Comment: @Dirty Penguin, The key is distinguishing string literals (source code such as `"123\x{34}567"`) and the strings they produce (values such as `1234567`).